# Ssh in ubuntu with different users - Why the console is working differently?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I usually connect to many Ubuntu servers with the same user (ubuntu). For the first time i have created a new user (elliot) for Ansible and I'm starting to ssh with the new one. The strange thing is that with the default user when I ssh I have:

> ubuntu@node2517

Everything works fine no problems. But if i ssh with the new user i have just:

> $

And I can't for example use autofill, I can't select the previous command. It looks like something is not working or missing.

My question is how can i have the new user to behave like the old one? This mean ssh on the server and see:

> elliot@node2517

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change the user's *shell.* The program which interprets your input (and displays the "prompt" text) is the shell, and most Linux systems come with two: `bash` is the regular one, but if you forget to specify it when creating an account, you get the historical `sh` instead.

(zsh and fish are also common choices, but they need to be installed first.)

You can use either `chsh` or `usermod` to change the shell path – the former command allows any user to do it themselves.

```
chsh -s /bin/bash elliot
```

(Note: When doing this as root, make sure to look at which shells are listed in the `/etc/shells` file first, as the system might refuse logins for users whose shells aren't in that file.)

Comment: Many thanks super!! it works perfectly!! s